# Cannot detect horizontal lines of an image

Tags: c++, image, opencv

I'm writing a mobile app to plot the graphical representation (graphs and charts) of images of statistical data tables. currently i'm writing the table detection module of the project using OpenCV with c++.

I have already applied adaptiveThreshold and Canny to detect the largest Contour and cropped out the table. (https://i.stack.imgur.com/q73CB.jpg)

and following is the code i'm using to detect the horizontal and vertical lines: Note: "Crop" is the already cropped table image(Mat)

```
cvtColor(crop, crop, CV_RGB2GRAY);
adaptiveThreshold(crop, crop, 255, CV_ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C,CV_THRESH_BINARY, 31, 15); 
    Mat dst1, cdst1;
Canny(crop, dst1, 50, 200, 3); 
cvtColor(dst1, cdst1, CV_GRAY2BGR); 

vector<Vec2f> lines;
// detect lines
HoughLines(dst1, lines, 1, CV_PI/180, 200, 0, 0 );
//HoughLinesP(dst1, lines, 1, CV_PI/180, 150, 0, 0);

// draw lines
for( size_t i = 0; i < lines.size(); i++ )
{
    float rho = lines[i][0], theta = lines[i][1];
    //if( theta>CV_PI/180*170 || theta<CV_PI/180*10){
        Point pt1, pt2;
        double a = cos(theta), b = sin(theta);
        double x0 = a*rho, y0 = b*rho;
        pt1.x = cvRound(x0 + 1000*(-b));
        pt1.y = cvRound(y0 + 1000*(a));
        pt2.x = cvRound(x0 - 1000*(-b));
        pt2.y = cvRound(y0 - 1000*(a));
        line( cdst1, pt1, pt2, Scalar(0,0,255), 3, CV_AA);
    //}
}
namedWindow("detected lines",WINDOW_NORMAL);
imshow("detected lines", cdst1);
```

And the result of this code comes out like this : https://i.stack.imgur.com/o3BKb.jpg

What am I going wrong to the Horizontal lines only to reach half of the image?

Comment: So basically you are trying to extract the table.

Comment: try to adjust the parameter of the Houghline function it'll help !

Comment: try the `HoughLinesP` function instead of `HoughLines`, I got very good results with that on different data.

Comment: @Haris yes im trying to get the intersection points and crop the all the cells to pass them to tesseract engine for OCR

Comment: @Engine and Micka thanks a lot for your replies. i will try that soon as possible

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you are trying to extract each cell in the table you can try contour processing,

- Do [**binary invert threshold**](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/threshold/threshold.html#threshold-binary-inverted)  in the source.

[image]

- [**Find contour**](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/shapedescriptors/find_contours/find_contours.html), here you should use RETR_EXTERNAL.
- Then [**draw contour**](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=drawcontours#drawcontours) with CV_FILLED, here you will get mask for your table. Notice that here you should get only one contour, and assumes there wont be any noise outside the table. Or if you got multiple contour draw largest as mask.

[image]

- **[Bitwise xor](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#bitwise-xor)** between threshold and mask

[image]

- Again Find contour, with RETR_EXTERNAL option. See the drawn contour  with CV_FILLED option.

[image]

- Calculate [**bounding Rect**](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/shapedescriptors/bounding_rects_circles/bounding_rects_circles.html) or [**Rotated rect**](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/shapedescriptors/bounding_rotated_ellipses/bounding_rotated_ellipses.html) for contour for further use.

See bounding rect.

[image]

See rotated rect.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I suspect your call to [HoughLines](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/feature_detection.html?highlight=houghlines#houghlines) is playing a role. If you tweak the *threshhold* parameter, you can get more appreciable results with increased or decreased lines.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. i will try this as soon as possible.