# Detecting the corners of a grid using Open Cv

Tags: java, opencv

I have a white grid on a black background:

[image]

I am trying to obtain the values of the corners (inner boxes as well). I tried using the Harris Corner Detector but it doesn't work very well (it doesn't work even if it is a perfect grid).

```
Imgproc.cornerHarris(tp, har, 2, 3, 0.04);
Core.normalize(har, har, 0, 255, Core.NORM_MINMAX, CvType.CV_32FC1, new Mat());
Core.convertScaleAbs(har, har);
```

To view the detected corners I am using

```
for(int i=0;i<har.height();i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<har.width();j++)
        {
            u=har.get(i, j);
            if(u[0] > 200)
            {
                Core.circle(cor, new Point(j,i), 6, new Scalar(255,0,0));
            }
        }
    }
```

Should I make any modification to the parameters? Or is there any other technique I could use? I would be grateful for any suggestions!

Comment: Have you tried findContours() ?

Comment: I checked it out. It said it would return an array of points. But will the order be predictable. Basically, I'm trying to extract the contents from each cell for further processing.

Comment: The grid is one large connected component that was obtained using a Floodfill.

Comment: @SidRama See the answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23078452/cannot-detect-horizontal-lines-of-an-image/23106594#23106594 might be helpful.

Comment: @Haris Thanks! That seems like a good idea. I'll try something on those lines.